# How to access the assets folder in angular solution when having different root locations

Tags: css, angular

I am having a css file in my assets/css folder, that needs to access some fonts in the assets/fonts folder. I can make it work localhost by writing url('/assets/fonts/myfont.svg').

On the server this isn't working because the path to the root of my site is mydomain.com/myapp/. I have changed the base from  to

Then I have tried:

- url('assets/fonts/myfont.svg')
- url('~assets/fonts/myfont.svg')
- url('./assets/fonts/myfont.svg')

But then the solution won't compile ( Can't resolve 'assets/fonts/myfont.svg')

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this url `~src/assets/fonts/myfont.svg`
It definitely works for me.

Comment: This only works because webpack in angular cli resolves all the relative, and absolute paths to work with the bundled app files in the dist folder.

Comment: When using the path ~src/assets/fonts/ i get a compile error: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare all your assets in your `angular.json` file like for example assets folder which is usually declared by default. That makes your assets folder directly available and after the build process, you would notice assets being transferred in the dist folder. Then to use anything from the assets you would write `/assets/img.png`. The slash before tells the link to take the directory from the root, whereas `assets/img.png` can sometimes be interpreted from the current directory.

Comment: But this isn't working when publishing it on my production server, because the root url for that website is "mydomain.com/myapp/" (And the base href is changed from "/" to "/myapp/"

Comment: then do `/myapp/assets/img.png`

Comment: But then it can't compile or run on localhost

Comment: Ok there is one other way to deal with it, it's changing your base url to accomodate the project, you can find one of the references in `index.html`

Comment: But I am already updating the base href in the index.html on behalf of the root of the website

Comment: Make sure your assets are placed inside dist this may sometime cause you issue. Ng build

Comment: In the project the assets is placed in the src folder along with the app and scss.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check `angular.json` and change the assets root like this

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

and the source root under projects like this:

```
"sourceRoot": "src",
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in `src/app/modules/model/test/test.component.ts`, if I want import something inside `src/assets`

from *.ts f.e.:

`'../../../../assets';`,

from *.html f.e.:

```
<img class="frame" src="assets/img/default.png">
```

from *.css f.e.:

```
@font-face {
  src: url('../../../../assets/fonts/myfont.svg');
}
```

you need to go back to the previous folder with `../` until you can reach your expected folder.

```
src
├── app ../
│   └── modules ../
│      └── model ../
│         └── test ../
├── assets
│   └── fonts
```